# Numeric Keypad ANdroid changes to alphanumeric keypad

Tags: android, android-keypad, android-textinputedittext

I have a textinputedittext with input type=number. To close the keypad if user clicks anywhere other than textinputedittext i used the following function -

```
public static void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity) {
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager =
            (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(
                    Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
            activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

But instead of keyboard getting closed , it simply converts to alpha-numeric(default) keyboard , and then when there is second click the the keyboard closes. 
I am unable to understand as to why the keyboard instead of closing converts to alpha-numeric.

Comment: This question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36889384/3640279) (Possible duplicate)

Comment: thanks @Dondani , though not duplicate but i got my solution

Comment: the issue was because of xml attribute focusableintouch mode , because of which the view was alays focused which was causing the keyboard isuue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

adding this attribute on parent layout of screen solved the issue.